# What is the username and password for Google Cloud Computing instance?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, cloud, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect to my Windows instance via FreeRDP.

What would be the username and password for my external IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Accroding [Google Compute Engine document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-passwords-for-windows-instances) you need reset password to get an account and password.